# Cannot convert FileList to Array using Array.from and spread syntax in typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, file, types

This line
`const files = Array.from(e.target.files);` produces an error in typescript.

I'm a newbie to typescript. It appears the object is not an array-like, but it actually is. What can I do to fix this?

The error is:

*"No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 4, '(iterable: Iterable | ArrayLike): File[]', gave the following error.
Argument of type 'FileList | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable | ArrayLike'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Iterable | ArrayLike'.
Overload 2 of 4, '(arrayLike: ArrayLike): File[]', gave the following error.
Argument of type 'FileList | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ArrayLike'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'ArrayLike'."*

Here's the code:

```js
import { ChangeEvent } from 'react';
import './styles.css';

export function App() {
  const handleFileLoad = function (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    const files = Array.from(e.target.files);
    // I want to use forEach here, so I attempt to convert it to an array.
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="file" onChange={handleFileLoad} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason why you're getting an error is because `files` in `e.target.files` might be null, which can cause `Array.from(e.target.files)` to error out, so TypeScript is sort of prompting you to provide a fall-back for that scenario.

Comment: That solves the problem as well, thank you.
`const files = Array.from(e.target.files || []);`

Answer (score 0):

you can use

> `(e.target as  HTMLInputElement).files`

instead of using

> `e.target`

as an direct object

Answer (score 0):

`e.target.files` returns a `FileList | null`, you can learn about FileList [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList).

You can see that you can iterate over the files with a regular for-loop:

```js
for(let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    const file = files[i]; // get single file from files array
    // do anything you want with the file
}
```

Comment: Of course, I can use a regular `for` loop. But in regular javascript, my code was totally valid (without typescript syntax, of course). So, I didn't know what typescript was not able to accept what I had written.
I've posted a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
This will do the job:

```js
const files = Array.from(e.target.files as ArrayLike<File>);
```

We can consider FileList to be an ArrayLike that contains  elements

For some reason, typescript didn't manage to guess it on its own.